# Creating a Function from svyglm

Tags: r, glm, predict, survey

I fit the following glm model using the survey package:

```
design <- svydesign(ids=training.data$name, design=design,family=quasibinomial(), data=training.data)
significant.model <- svyglm(Win~x+ y + start+ speed+ vx0 + vy0 + ay + az + length+ rate+ height+ hand+ zone+ count, design=design, family=quasibinomial, data=training.data)
```

I have a set of test data that I excluded from the model fitting process so that I would be able to see how the model predicts the outcomes for the test data and examine the difference.

Typically, I would use makeFun in the mosaic package, but this does not support objects of type svyglm. Is there another function or method that I can use to create a function for the model?

There are a lot of categorical variables with multiple levels, so writing a user-defined function is not ideal in this situation.

Comment: could you clarify why you cannot use the `predict` function?

Comment: I have used predict(significant.model, data=test.data), but it still does the predictions for the training data.

Comment: i'm pretty sure it doesn't do that.  according to the `?survey:::predict.svyglm` help page you want `newdata=` and not `data=`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what difficulty you were experiencing since your example is not reproducible.  But since an `svyglm` object *is* a `glm` object, `makeFun()` will create a wrapper around `predict()` just as it would do for any `glm` object.  This has not been tested extensively, but it seems to work in the following example:

`r
example(svyglm)
f <- makeFun(api.reg)
f(enroll = 500)`